# Transaction will not confirm!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Big transaction, sender put good miner fee on it but it is not confirming. Can anyone help me or tell me why it isn't confirming?

https://blockchain.info/tx/a95f4d5fa41b194454bdd6d665f002ec31b5e8b25c12bc22c39497f2a7139b2f

Comment: Nobody can tell me why or help me out? :(

Comment: It was confirmed 7.5 hours after you submitted it.

Answer (score 3):

Although the fee is roughly 0.0002 BTC/KByte (corresonds to 20 Satoshis/Byte), at the moment there is a congestion of transactions happening in the network, with roughly 30,000 unconfirmed transactions:
https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/

Therefore the required fee has increased dramatically for high priority transactions:
https://bitcoinfees.21.co/#delay

So it looks like your transaction fee should have been three times as high to be regarded with high priority.

But just wait some more time, the transaction should be confirmed soon.

Comment: Oh thank you. Can I add more fee to get it to speed up? Or is it too late now

Comment: What wallet are you using? Some of them do allow to double spend your own transaction using a higher fee.